# java Streams, How to groupby Map based on key with values of arraylist

Tags: java

I have an Employee class

```
class Employee{ 
    int id;
    String name;    
    Employee(int id, String name){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;     
    }   
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

in my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Map<String, List<Employee>> firstMap = new HashMap<>();
         firstMap.put("depa", Arrays.asList(new Employee(1,"aa")) );
         firstMap.put("depA", Arrays.asList(new Employee(2,"bb")));
         firstMap.put("depC", Arrays.asList(new Employee(3,"cc")));
         firstMap.put("depd", Arrays.asList(new Employee(4,"dd")));
         firstMap.put("depak", Arrays.asList(new Employee(5,"A1"),new Employee(6,"A2")) );
         firstMap.put("depaK", Arrays.asList(new Employee(7,"A3")) );
         firstMap.put("depAk", Arrays.asList(new Employee(8,"A4")) );
         firstMap.put("depAK", Arrays.asList(new Employee(9,"A5")) );

}
```

From this I wan to convert all Keys to capitals then groupby the keys and values should be added to the list.

I have tried this:

```
Map<Object, List<Object>> secondMap = firstMap.entrySet().
                 stream().
                 collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m->m.getKey().toUpperCase(),
                 Collectors.mapping(
                         el->el.getValue(), Collectors.toList())));
```

But I am getting Map<Object, List> here where I want to get Map<String, List>.
Here I am getting List<list> as values but I want list as values

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the downstream collector of `groupingBy`, you should use the `flatMapping` collector, instead of the `mapping` collector. `mapping` would produce a `Map<String, List<List<Employee>>>`.

Each group contains multiple `List<Employee>`, and you want to *flatten* them into a single `List<Employee>`.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> secondMap = firstMap.entrySet().
        stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m->m.getKey().toUpperCase(),
                Collectors.flatMapping(
                        el->el.getValue().stream(), Collectors.toList())));
```